# Remove 'is missing from working copy' alerts in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alert

We are trying to remove the Zendesk support previously used in our app, however when we removed it, we ended up with around 200 alerts, saying "(file path) is missing from the working copy." Although this is not effecting our app from running, the alerts are annoying, we have tried updating Xcode but no luck.

Does anyone know how to remove these alerts?

Comment: please provide more detail.

Comment: we removed the framework, but now we get alerts saying ...'is missing from working copy

Answer (score 3):

Xcode warns you that you have removed files from the working copy, which are checked in to your repository (git?).

Simply commit your changes to get rid of the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This error normally occurs when you haven't committed. Simply try committing current changes!

If that does not remove the error try the following:

**Try cleaning the project.**

If that does not work do the following:

1. **Go to Build phases.**
2. **Link Binary with libraries.**
3. **Select your framework that you want to remove and press minus button down there.**

Failing that, try deleting derived data by doing `Shift+Alt+Command+K`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In your project setting -> build setting -> search path.

Check there if your SDK path are there then remove it from framework search path or Header search path.

Comment: Hi, there is nothing in those search paths

Answer (score 0):

The warning will disappear as soon as you commit your changes (Xcode 8)